# Is it sunnah to make group dua after Fard jamaath prayer?

Tags: salat, dua, jamaat, imam-al-jamaah

I know that it is sunnah of prophet(PBUH) to make group dua and say ameen for that.

But, my question is

Is it sunnah to make group dua after Fard jamaath prayer?

In our area(Tamilnadu, India) we had a practice of asking group dua after jamaath of every fard prayer(ie, imaam will ask dua immediately after salaam). But, when I went to north India there such thing does not exists. Is it a bid'ah?

Comment: How do you **know that it is sunnah to make group dua and say ameen for that**? If you do know of any source for this sort of action, I'd like to know it, please. Jazaakallaahu khairan

Answer (score 3):

To make ***group Dua'***, some one making dua' and the rest saying Ameen, is ok if done only  on occasions.  But if it is taken as a constant practice on every such occasions then it becomes a Bid'ah/Innovation.  So it is an innovation to do ***Group Dua'*** after each and every Fard Salat.  The place for Dua' in regards to Salat is on an individual level, the place is before the Tasleem and after it, regardless of whether the salat is fard or not.

Answer (score 0):

Dua after salaat is an innovation - some say it is a good one - I have my doubts. The prophet (PBUH) said that dua should be made before the salaam of completing salaat.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we recommend you check out our [help].